# angular 4 unit test input text box (behavior) click / focus

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-test

I'm trying to unit test my component and in one test i want to focus / click the input text box. This is because when we click input text it opens a modal and i want to make sure the action happens.

This may be possible in e2e test but wanted to achieve it in unit testing due to a requirement.

**HTML template**

```
<input type="text" class="search"/>
```

**component.spec.ts**

assuming that the test bed module configuration is fine.

```
...
it('focus the input element', () => {
   let searchTextBox: DebugElement = this.fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('search')).nativeElement;
   serachTextBox.click(); // is this possible or anything else
   fixture.detectChanges();
   ...
});
```

*i am sorry that i couldn't share the entire code.*

Comment: Yes, this should be possible. I assume when you click on the input box you call some method, your test should spyon that method and expect for it to be called. You can write a different test to test the implementation of the modal opening. I would only care that the click calls the right method. My only concern is using click on an input box to show a modal..

Comment: on 2nd thought I would care that it called the service that opens the modal

Answer (score 0):

```
...
it('focus the input element', () => {
   let searchTextBox: DebugElement = this.fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('search')).nativeElement;
   spyOn(someObject,'showModal')
   serachTextBox.click(); // is this possible or anything else
   expect(someObject.showModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
   ...
});
```